# Need pagination for liquid photo gallery module in Adobe business catalyst

Tags: liquid, business-catalyst

All the images are loaded in same page, how could I control using pagination? 
Any one can help me to solve this problem.

Here is my code.

```
{module_photogallery id="123456" collection="test2016" template="" }
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        {% for item in test2016.items %}
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <a onclick="myLightbox.start(this);return false;" rel="lightbox[photo2015]" href="{{item.link}}">
                <img src="{{item.link}}?Action=thumbnail&Width=250&Height=150&algorithm=fill_proportional">
            </a>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can accomplish this by following this article: http://docs.businesscatalyst.com/developers/liquid/pagination-for-module_data. If you need any specific help, please update your question.

Answer (score 5):

BC provides the pagination object to accomplish exactly that.
This object gives you 6 parameters: currentPage, itemsPerPage, numberOfPages, totalItemsCount, previousPageUrl, nextPageUrl. 
First of all you'll need to add a resultsPerPage="" to the initial photogallery module tag, then add, for instance, {{test2016.pagination.previousPageUrl}} as the href of an anchor tag to get a previous page link.

It would depend on what you want, but you could end up with something like this:

```
{module_photogallery id="12345" resultsPerPage="6" collection="test2016" template="" }
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        {% for item in test2016.items %}
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <a onclick="myLightbox.start(this);return false;" rel="lightbox[photo2015]" href="{{item.link}}">
                <img src="{{item.link}}?Action=thumbnail&Width=250&Height=150&algorithm=fill_proportional">
            </a>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}

        <a href="{{test2016.pagination.previousPageUrl}}">Prev</a> <a href="{{test2016.pagination.nextPageUrl}}">Next</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Use a few if...then statements and some of the other parameters to get exactly what you want.